# What is the meaning of the [sgd] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-excerpt

The tag [sgd](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sgd) has no usage information. I do not know what it is for, anybody knows, and can provide a wiki?

Comment: Stochastic Gradient Descent?

Comment: The tag seems to have been created by @avocado [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/201279/). This is an example of our [perennial problem](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3177/) w/ people using acronyms w/o defining them; "SVD" is never defined in either the question or the answer.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, that seems to be the answer, why not make it an 'official' answer here, & create an excerpt for the tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote the following wiki excerpt:

> Stochastic gradient descent (SGD) is a variant of gradient descent where only a small subset ("mini-batch") of training examples is used to compute the gradient on each iteration.

Feel free to improve.

---

It might make sense to create a synonym `[stochastic-gradient-descent]`$\to$[sgd](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sgd).

**Update: done.**

Comment: Please create the synonym!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, amoeba, I created the synonym [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/sgd/synonyms).

Comment: @gung maybe we should swap the synonyms so the full form is the basic tag and sgd is a synonym? PS I created meta thread for this: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5022/should-the-default-tag-synonyms-be-in-the-full-form-or-abbreviated

Comment: That's potentially fine w/ me, @Tim. My 1st thought is that people who ask / answer about this seem to have preferred the short version, so we might take that into account. It might also be worth discussing. What do amoeba, Kjetil, & Matt think, eg?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, see comments above. Do you have a preference?

Comment: @gung I have no preference.

Comment: I'd prefer the full version be primary, and I'd prefer that was our general rule!