# Should the default tag synonyms be in the full form or abbreviated?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have multiple synonyms for full-form names and their abbreviations like [item-response-theory](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/item-response-theory) and [irt](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irt), or [stochastic-gradient-descent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-gradient-descent) and [sgd](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sgd). What should be the basic form: full length or abbreviated? The labels can be easily swapped.

Comment: Upvote here if you prefer the full form.

Comment: Upvote here if you prefer the abbreviated form.

Comment: I think the preferred form should depend on how widespread/well-known the acronym is. E.g. [pca] and [svd] are IMHO fine. But obscure abbreviations are not good as tag names. Where to draw the line, I don't know.

Comment: @amoeba but what is "widespread" and "obscure" may depend on your background...

Comment: OK, but de-abbreviating e.g. [anova] or [arima] seems like an overkill. "Autoregressive integrated moving average" won't even fit as a tag name.

Answer (score 11):

**Let the users decide in each case.**

When creating synonyms, I have always chosen as the "target" (which is the name that will be displayed) the one most commonly used on the site.

The advantages of this procedure are evident: our tags reflect the values people naturally think of.

The disadvantage would be an apparent inconsistency--sometimes a target would be longer than its synonyms, sometimes shorter.  But of what value would such a consistency be?  I cannot see any.

Comment: +1, this is my default policy as well.

Comment: I don't agree personally, I really prefer the full name be used.  Yet, this is a very sensible argument, so I support it.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Would you prefer the full name to be used for "ANOVA"? "ARIMA"? My personal preference would *in the vast majority of situations* be for full names, but there are a few things which are better-known by their abbreviations. I am upvoting this answer because I suspect, in practice, most of the time that it's sensible, users will prefer fuller names.

Comment: @Silverfish I wrote don't a detailed description of my thoughts on this here: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3177/74500

Comment: @Matthew Ah, great post, I've (+1)ed it in the past but forgot it was you who wrote it or that we had discussed it before! It did get a lot of support in that thread, which suggests that many users see abbreviations as (often) unnecessarily ambiguous.