# Should we have a canonical question about coincidences?

Tags: discussion, tags, closing-questions, exact-duplicates

Right now, [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/close/200570) is marked for closing as a duplicate of [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296541/determining-statistical-probability-related-to-a-string-event-of-dates). Yet the titles and subjects are totally different at first glance - and someone searching for something similar will have little hope of finding this.

Of course, a little thought makes us realize both are about analyzing coincidences. But we don't have such a tag (at least, I could not find one) and neither of the two questions is really canonical.

Should we have some question such as "How can one analyze the probability of coincidences?" ?   Or should we just add a tag?

Comment: +1.  I would just like to point out that for a long time we have had a canonical *link* to reply to such questions: see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3207/919.

Answer (score 3):

We should definitely have a canonical answer since these questions crop up all the time. I wrote the answer linked above, the intention was that it could be used as canonical answer, and has been used as dup target at least once. So if a better one is wanted ...

Comment: I think the issue is that we need a better *question*.  Something like "How can coincidences be analyzed using statistics and probability?" (although maybe not exactly that).

Comment: Could you try to write that?

Comment: I think what I have is a good first draft.  Maybe others will have suggestions for improving it.

Comment: @PeterFlom, you could just post the question, & people could comment &/or edit as needed.

Comment: @Peter Flom: Did you have any advance? We need that question so we can close as dups, for instance today this one:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193091/sexuality-of-dog-owner

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @Peter Flom: I just referred to your own old comments in this thread. ??? Or do you know of some other question now that can be used as a canonical dup target?

Comment: I don't.  But I think we can mark it as a dup of yours and then change the wording or something.  Or maybe one of us can ask a canonical one and mark both as dups.

Comment: For now I vote to close as a dup of my, and we can change if we got something better.